# Ruby on Rails code for converting TeX to PNG on the server side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, png, wikipedia, tex

I am creating a Ruby on Rails app very similar to Wikipedia. In Wikipedia you can add math equations to a page using TeX/LaTeX. Then when you preview the page these TeX equations are converted to PNG images on the server side and the images are embedded in the text. Are you aware of a code that I can use to do that in Rails? There is a gem rails-latex but that doesn't do it. As far as I know MathJax doesn't do that either.

Comment: Hope it will give your answer  Please try this gem https://github.com/jeffmcfadden/markdown_preview

Comment: This gem is for Markdown Preview. I'm not sure how it helps to covert tex to png?

Comment: For text to image you can use https://github.com/citrus/magick_title or `gem install magick_title` `MagickTitle.say("Hello")` and check `/public/system/title`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MediaWiki uses Texvc to create png images from tex. see: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Texvc

Texvc is an external program, so you have to start it via system() and save the result in a special folder.
For example like this:

```
 system('texvc /home/wiki/tmp /home/wiki/math "y=x+2" iso-8859-1 "rgb 1.0 1.0 1.0"')
```